# How to autocomplete filename in your path on the command line when in a different directory in windows7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, autocomplete

on the windows command line I can autocomplete any filename/subdirectory by typing a few letters and then pressing Tab. Is there a way to extend this to anything that is in my PATH.

Example:

In my path I have the program *verylongfilename.exe*

In a command window that is currently in c:\temp I can type 
verylongfilename.exe to run the program.

If I put *verylongfilename.exe* in c:\temp,
I can type *very* and then press *tab* to autocomplete.
If *verylongfilename.exe* is in a different directory within the path, I always have to type the file name completely.

Any way around this without installing third party tools?

Answer (score 4):

From a CMD prompt or the run box, type "powershell" to give you what [you're wanting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion).

Answer (score 1):

Please use this command

```
cmd /f
```

which activates autofill.

Then type in atleast one letter of the file (or) folder name,

Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to autofill , if there more than one file (or) folder name which starts with the same letter,Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to cycle through the list.

Another choice is to drag and drop the file to cmd window, to get the entire path of the field.

Comment: What? Are you talking about when you start the Command Prompt? And how does it know what the user is looking for, if it searches every directory?

Comment: Tried this, but this does nothing when I type a few letters of the program name

Answer (score -2):

doing cmd /? at the bottom of the help screen explains:

If completion is enabled with the /F:ON switch

Try that

I Just tried it from an open command console and it didn't work
However if you click the Start Icon then search for CMD /F:ON it 
brings up a command window with completion enabled as the first
poster explains

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.